# Retrieving data dependent on attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server

everyone. I can't do the following query. Please help.
Initial data and ouput are on the following excel [initial data/output google/drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwcVwVHkHN8SRGNqYVVXOU5mRUE/edit?usp=sharing)

Here is the logic: for 'Rest' = 2500, it takes minimum value of 'Date', increments it by one and put it into Date1 column of output; Date2 receives the minimum value of date of the next 'Rest' value (1181,85).. and so on: Date1 receives 'Rest' (1181,85) min value of 'Date'(14.01.2013) incremented by one (15.01.2013) and so on. It should not do the above operations for 'Rest' value of zero (it should just skip it). We can't initially delete rows with 'Rest' value of zero, because their Date is used in Date2, as I have explained above. There are many 'accNumber's, it should list all of them. Please help. I hope you understood, if not ask for more details. Thanks in advance. I'm using SQL server.

Comment: 1. You are better off posting a small bit of sample data and expected output directly on SO (i.e. don't expect people to download random documents) 2. It would be nice to see any attempt you have made.

Comment: It does not allow to put it right here, since I have reoutation less than 10, the only way to show data is google drive.

Comment: select a.accNumber, a.Rest, min(a.Date),  min(b.Date)  from Table1  a, Table1 b  
where b.Date>a.Date
and a.accNumber=b.accNumber
and a.Rest<>b.Rest
Group by a.accNumber, a.Rest  
order by a.accNumber, 3

Comment: above code works, but it doesn't take into account 'zero' stuff

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, you want to group the items by rest number, and then display the minimum date + 1 day, as well as the minimum date for the "next" rest number.  What are you expecting to happen when the Rest number is 0 in two different places?

```
with Base as
(
    select    t.AccNum,
              t.Rest,
              DATEADD(day, 1, MIN(t.Date)) as [StartDate],
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MIN(t.Date)) as RowNumber
    from      Accounts t
    where     t.Rest <> 0
    group by  t.AccNum, t.Rest
)
select      a.AccNum, a.Rest, a.StartDate, DATEADD(DAY, -1, b.StartDate) as [EndDate]
from        Base a
left join   Base b
on          a.RowNumber = b.RowNumber - 1
order by a.[StartDate]
```

If there's the possibility of the Rest number being duplicated further down, but that needing to be a separate item, then we need to be a bit cleverer in our initial select query.

```
with Base as
(
    select  b.AccNum, b.Rest, MIN(DATEADD(day, 1, b.Date)) as [StartDate], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MIN(Date)) as [RowNumber]
    from    (
        select  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Rest ORDER BY Date) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) as [Order]
        from    Accounts a
     -- where  a.Rest <> 0 
     -- If we're still filtering out Rest 0 uncomment the above line
    ) b
    group by [order], AccNum, Rest
)
select      a.RowNumber, a.AccNum, a.Rest, a.StartDate, DATEADD(DAY, -1, b.StartDate) as [EndDate]
from        Base a
left join   Base b
on          a.RowNumber = b.RowNumber - 1
order by a.[StartDate]
```

Results for both queries:

```
Account Number          REST    Start Date  End Date
45817840200000057948    2500    2013-01-01  2013-01-14
45817840200000057948    1181    2013-01-15  2013-01-31
45817840200000057948    2431    2013-02-01  2013-02-09
45817840200000057948    1563    2013-02-10  NULL
```

Comment: It should just skip rows with 0 'Rest' values wherever they are

Comment: OK, see my edited answer, and a further edit incase the rest number can be repeated further down, but should be considered as a separate transaction.

Comment: it gives the following result https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwcVwVHkHN8Sd0VkUWdaal8wNGs/edit?usp=sharing something very different. I guess you understand the logic. Plese, could you  please review your answer. I can't come up with correct way to do it for 3 days(( Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you using the whole query? Edit: added results to post.

Comment: another question, how to select only the last row of each accNumber in initial data. thanks

Comment: Maybe it is due to my stupidity, I'm totally new in sql. I'll try it once more. One remark: it should be 2013-02-21, instead of null. Maybe it does not work due to syntax?

Comment: I think you need to change any reference to `AccNum` to `AccNumber`, but if you take either one of those queries in their entirety you should get the results as above.  The reason the last row is null is because you asked me to filter out where `rest = 0`.  If you use the second query and move the `where a.Rest <> 0` to the second last line, that'll give you the desired results.

Comment: Take a look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/136b9/3/0) with your sample data

Comment: Thanks a lot @mathew I did everything what you say, but I receive different results. Reading SQL for dummies would be better idea for me now.))

Comment: Did you check out the link to the SQL fiddle? That shows you exactly the table structure I used, the query and the results I get back from it.

Comment: yep. most probably I need to revise syntax, because I use different software))